# Can't make my header fixed whilst my table is scrollable

Tags: html, css

My code works almost as I want it however after some research and trying I finally made my table scrollable however I can't seem to make the header stay fixed no matter what I try, could someone be able to help?
I need the header to be fixed so you can still see the headings when you scroll down the table of course.

```css
.my-custom-scrollbar {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.table-wrapper-scroll-y {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="myScript.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Users</title>
  <meta name="description" content="APP Web Task 5">
  <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">
</head>
<!--Text body-->

<body>
  <!--header-->

  <header class="container jumbotron text-center">
    <h2>APP Single Page App</h2>
  </header>

  <!--Section 1, table-->
  <div class="container">
    <section id="sectUsers">
      <div class="table-wrapper-scroll-y my-custom-scrollbar">
        <table id="tblUsers" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-fixed">
          <!--Table header-->
          <thead class="table table-bordered table-primary table-striped text-center">
            <tr id="tblUserHeader">
              <th scope="col">User ID</th>
              <th scope="col">Email</th>
              <th scope="col">First Name</th>
              <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
              <th scope="col">Avatar</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <!--Table body-->
          <tbody class="table table-bordered">
            <tr id="user1">
              <td scope="row"><b>1</b></td>
              <td>george.bluth@reqres.in</td>
              <td>George</td>
              <td class="w3-center">Bluth</td>
              <td>
                <div><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/calebogden/128.jpg" alt="avatar" class="rounded-circle"></div>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr id="user2">
              <td scope="row"><b>2</b></td>
              <td>janet.weaver@reqres.in</td>
              <td>Janet</td>
              <td class="w3-center">Weaver</td>
              <td>
                <div><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/josephstein/128.jpg" alt="avatar" class="rounded-circle"></div>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr id="user3">
              <td scope="row"><b>3</b></td>
              <td>emma.wong@reqres.in</td>
              <td>Emma</td>
              <td class="w3-center">Wong</td>
              <td>
                <div><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/olegpogodaev/128.jpg" alt="avatar" class="rounded-circle"></div>
              </td>
            </tr>


            <tr id="user4">
              <td scope="row"><b>4</b></td>
              <td>eve.holt@reqres.in</td>
              <td>Eve</td>
              <td class="w3-center">Holt</td>
              <td>
                <div><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/marcoramires/128.jpg" alt="avatar" class="rounded-circle"></div>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr id="user5">
              <td scope="row"><b>5</b></td>
              <td>charles.morris@reqres.in</td>
              <td>Charles</td>
              <td>Morris</td>
              <td>
                <div><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/stephenmoon/128.jpg" alt="avatar" class="rounded-circle"></div>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr id="user6">
              <td scope="row"><b>6</b></td>
              <td>tracey.ramos@reqres.in</td>
              <td>Tracey</td>
              <td>Ramos</td>
              <td>
                <div><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/bigmancho/128.jpg" alt="avatar" class="rounded-circle"></div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>

          <!--    <div id="divPageNumber">Page<span id="pageNumber">1</span> of <span id="totalPages">2</span></div>
                      <button id="btnPrevious" >Previous</button><button id="btnNext" >Next</button> -->
      </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to th

```
position:sticky;
top:0;
```

```css
.my-custom-scrollbar {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.table-wrapper-scroll-y {
  display: block;
}
.my-custom-scrollbar table th {
  background:#b8daff;
  position:sticky;
  top:0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="myScript.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Users</title>
  <meta name="description" content="APP Web Task 5">
  <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">
</head>
<!--Text body-->

<body>
  <!--header-->

  <header class="container jumbotron text-center">
    <h2>APP Single Page App</h2>
  </header>

  <!--Section 1, table-->
  <div class="container">
    <section id="sectUsers">
      <div class="table-wrapper-scroll-y my-custom-scrollbar">
        <table id="tblUsers" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-fixed">
          <!--Table header-->
          <thead class="table table-bordered table-primary table-striped text-center">
            <tr id="tblUserHeader">
              <th scope="col">User ID</th>
              <th scope="col">Email</th>
              <th scope="col">First Name</th>
              <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
              <th scope="col">Avatar</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <!--Table body-->
          <tbody class="table table-bordered">
            <tr id="user1">
              <td scope="row"><b>1</b></td>
              <td>george.bluth@reqres.in</td>
              <td>George</td>
              <td class="w3-center">Bluth</td>
              <td>
                <div><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/calebogden/128.jpg" alt="avatar" class="rounded-circle"></div>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr id="user2">
              <td scope="row"><b>2</b></td>
              <td>janet.weaver@reqres.in</td>
              <td>Janet</td>
              <td class="w3-center">Weaver</td>
              <td>
                <div><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/josephstein/128.jpg" alt="avatar" class="rounded-circle"></div>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr id="user3">
              <td scope="row"><b>3</b></td>
              <td>emma.wong@reqres.in</td>
              <td>Emma</td>
              <td class="w3-center">Wong</td>
              <td>
                <div><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/olegpogodaev/128.jpg" alt="avatar" class="rounded-circle"></div>
              </td>
            </tr>


            <tr id="user4">
              <td scope="row"><b>4</b></td>
              <td>eve.holt@reqres.in</td>
              <td>Eve</td>
              <td class="w3-center">Holt</td>
              <td>
                <div><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/marcoramires/128.jpg" alt="avatar" class="rounded-circle"></div>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr id="user5">
              <td scope="row"><b>5</b></td>
              <td>charles.morris@reqres.in</td>
              <td>Charles</td>
              <td>Morris</td>
              <td>
                <div><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/stephenmoon/128.jpg" alt="avatar" class="rounded-circle"></div>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr id="user6">
              <td scope="row"><b>6</b></td>
              <td>tracey.ramos@reqres.in</td>
              <td>Tracey</td>
              <td>Ramos</td>
              <td>
                <div><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/bigmancho/128.jpg" alt="avatar" class="rounded-circle"></div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>

          <!--    <div id="divPageNumber">Page<span id="pageNumber">1</span> of <span id="totalPages">2</span></div>
                      <button id="btnPrevious" >Previous</button><button id="btnNext" >Next</button> -->
      </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following css with a little bit of js :

CSS

```
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

JS

```
window.onscroll = function() {stickyHeaderFunction()};
var header = document.getElementById("your_header");
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

function stickyHeaderFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    header.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use the `th`(header) to `stick`.

```
th {
 background: white;
 position: sticky;
 top: 0;
 box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

**Demo:**

```css
.my-custom-scrollbar {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.table-wrapper-scroll-y {
  display: block;
}

th {
  background: #B8DAFF;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.table {
  border-collapse: separate;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="myScript.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Users</title>
  <meta name="description" content="APP Web Task 5">
  <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">
</head>
<!--Text body-->

<body>
  <!--header-->

  <header class="container jumbotron text-center">
    <h2>APP Single Page App</h2>
  </header>

  <!--Section 1, table-->
  <div class="container">
    <section id="sectUsers">
      <div class="table-wrapper-scroll-y my-custom-scrollbar">
        <table id="tblUsers" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-fixed">
          <!--Table header-->
          <thead class="table table-bordered table-primary table-striped text-center">
            <tr id="tblUserHeader">
              <th scope="col">User ID</th>
              <th scope="col">Email</th>
              <th scope="col">First Name</th>
              <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
              <th scope="col">Avatar</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <!--Table body-->
          <tbody class="table table-bordered">
            <tr id="user1">
              <td scope="row"><b>1</b></td>
              <td>george.bluth@reqres.in</td>
              <td>George</td>
              <td class="w3-center">Bluth</td>
              <td>
                <div><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/calebogden/128.jpg" alt="avatar" class="rounded-circle"></div>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr id="user2">
              <td scope="row"><b>2</b></td>
              <td>janet.weaver@reqres.in</td>
              <td>Janet</td>
              <td class="w3-center">Weaver</td>
              <td>
                <div><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/josephstein/128.jpg" alt="avatar" class="rounded-circle"></div>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr id="user3">
              <td scope="row"><b>3</b></td>
              <td>emma.wong@reqres.in</td>
              <td>Emma</td>
              <td class="w3-center">Wong</td>
              <td>
                <div><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/olegpogodaev/128.jpg" alt="avatar" class="rounded-circle"></div>
              </td>
            </tr>


            <tr id="user4">
              <td scope="row"><b>4</b></td>
              <td>eve.holt@reqres.in</td>
              <td>Eve</td>
              <td class="w3-center">Holt</td>
              <td>
                <div><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/marcoramires/128.jpg" alt="avatar" class="rounded-circle"></div>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr id="user5">
              <td scope="row"><b>5</b></td>
              <td>charles.morris@reqres.in</td>
              <td>Charles</td>
              <td>Morris</td>
              <td>
                <div><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/stephenmoon/128.jpg" alt="avatar" class="rounded-circle"></div>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr id="user6">
              <td scope="row"><b>6</b></td>
              <td>tracey.ramos@reqres.in</td>
              <td>Tracey</td>
              <td>Ramos</td>
              <td>
                <div><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/bigmancho/128.jpg" alt="avatar" class="rounded-circle"></div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>

          <!--    <div id="divPageNumber">Page<span id="pageNumber">1</span> of <span id="totalPages">2</span></div>
                      <button id="btnPrevious" >Previous</button><button id="btnNext" >Next</button> -->
      </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Thanks! It works wonderfully however there seems to be a little bit at the top that when you scroll you can see the columns at the top of the header, it's really short in height, but it's a detail I guess some might notice! However, other than that this worked perfectly thanks again!

Comment: @MajaBobrowicz yes he accepted my answer which is the same, although  the 1px space Maja is talking about exists on my code too since we have the same solution, you just can add -1px instead of 0 on the top..-> top:-1px; which solve the problem

Comment: Hey @ZiadDarwich sorry for checking late! `top:-1;` will not work since it will not make table header as sticky, I have modified the code. you need to add a `border-collapse` property to not to view the gap above header!

Comment: We can also fix using other options as well but this is kind of simple way.